# Have two questions on the small project, one about Flexbox other about Grid

Tags: css, flexbox, grid

https://xvicissitudex.github.io/Basic_Website_Template/

Used Flex Box for the Nav bar. However I want it to be more responsive as it shrinks, especially the text. To get it responsive I added a media query at 600px.

```
`nav_main {
    display: flex;
    margin: 0px;
    padding-left: 1rem;
    list-style-type: none;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
    .nav_main {
    font-size: 1.2rem;
    }
    li {
        padding: .4rem;
    }
} 

`
```

But is there another way to get the flex children to shrink along viewport? I was trying flex shrink property but that only works when you want one flex item to shrink more than the others not when you want them all to shrink in unison.

The blue background was set up with grid:

```
`.blue {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat( auto-fit, minmax(350px, 1fr));
    grid-gap: 20px;
    padding: 20px;
}`
```

My question is how do I center the content once the grid items get pushed down to the second row.For example on a 24" motitor there are 5 grid items on first row, and 3 on second. I want to center second row. justify-content: center does nothing.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about your first question.

But for the second one you can check out this site with great explanation - https://css-irl.info/controlling-leftover-grid-items/

Comment: Don't post links to the answer, post your answer as external sites might be unavailable in the future.

Comment: Taken from the article:

"The above examples won’t work if you’re using CSS Grid’s auto-fill and auto-fit keywords instead of a fixed number of column tracks, because (without some fairly complex calculations) you can’t be sure of how many items will be on a grid row at any one time. auto-fill and auto-fit are quite useful in that they can deliver a responsive layout without the need for media queries – your grid responds to the containing block."

I am going to try to play around with it but it seems like it might not be a solution.